# Permanent redirect while reverse proxying with nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have setup an nginx reverse proxy server which proxy blog.xxx.com to xxx.com/blog. Here is my config file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name xxx.com www.xxx.com;
    
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /tmp/letsencrypt/www;
    }
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {

    listen 443;
    
    server_name xxx.com;
    
    root /var/www/html;

    include /etc/nginx/snippet/ssl.conf;
    
    location /blog/ {
        proxy_pass https://blog.xxx.com;
        proxy_set_header Host blog.xxx.com;
        rewrite /blog/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        expires -1;
        add_header Cache-Control no-store;
        proxy_read_timeout 90;
        proxy_connect_timeout 90;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://xxx:8090;
    }
    
}
```

It works just fine. But I need to have a permanent redirect on `blog.xxx.com` to `xxx.com/blog` as well. Once I set the redirect rule, a too many redirects situation happens.

Is there any way to have both reverse proxy and 301 redirect at the same time?

Comment: Where is your `server` block for `blog.xxx.com`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it is hosted on siteground, but I have full control over its config.

Comment: I mean you have not put it in your post.